# Sorting array into alphabetical order in Python

Tags: python

I have an array called names with a list of 4 names.

e.g

```
Names[1]='John'
```

I want to get the program to sort my array so that FOR each item in the array, except the last one, IF the item is bigger than the next one, swap the two items.

Comment: Are you asking "how do I sort a list of strings"?

Comment: Essentially. With the use of 4 identifiers.

Comment: I'm ... not sure what you mean by '4 identifiers'. Is what you want not just `names.sort()`?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is example input and desired output. You are wasting our time and your own time if you are so unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Like this??

```
names = [ 'Zac' , 'John',  'Andrew' , 'James' ]
for name in sorted(names[:-1]) + [names[-1]]:
    print name
Andrew
John
Zac
James
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work? Are you sure "[:-1]" is intentional?

Comment: I get the error:

line 10, in <module>
    for Name in sorted(Names[:-1]) + Names[-1]:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

Comment: The [:-1] is so that the last item in the list is excluded from the sort operation. We then append the last item onto the sorted list with `+ names[-1]`

Comment: Python 3, and you've used different bracket types, around both times you've used Names, does that matter?

Comment: yes and no. the parantheses () are used to pass arguments to a function - sorted() is a built-in function. The square brackets are used to create a list / array on the fly.

Comment: In python 3, the use of print was changed so that it's always called as a function. For the above code to work in python3, the print line needs to be changed to have parentheses around name. i.e. `print(name)`